# HttpErrorResponse Error 400

Tags: angular, api, .net, asp, https

HOLA gente vengo aca porque tengo un error de hace dias al momento de mi frontend intenta hacerder a mi api hecha en .net me genera el siguiente error desde mi backend hice la prueba con postman y todo me salio bien el problema es cuando angular manda la peticion a mi api tambien LES COMPARTO mi configuracion de Cors para ver si el problema es de ahí ya que e visto varias configuraciones entonces no se si esta sirve, mi db esta en SQL usando un docker container añado el backend y coloco lo que me dice el network de la consola al parecer me sale un error en mi variable fechaExpedicion aun que no entiendo cual seria

```
export class TarjetaCreditoComponent implements OnInit {

  form: FormGroup | any;


  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private tarjetaService: TarjetaService) {

   this.form= this.formBuilder.group({
     id:0,
     titular:  ["",[Validators.required]],
     numeroTarjeta:  ["",[Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(16),Validators.minLength(16)]],
     fechaExpiracion:["",[Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(5),Validators.minLength(5)]],
      cvv:["",[Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(3),Validators.minLength(3)]]
    });


  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

  guardarTarjeta(){
    const tarjeta: TarjetaCredito={
      titular:this.form.get('titular')?.value,
      numeroTarjeta:this.form.get('numeroTarjeta')?.value,
      fechaExpedicion:this.form.get('fechaExpedicion')?.value,
      cvv:this.form.get('cvv')?.value


    }
    this.tarjetaService.guardarTarjeta(tarjeta).subscribe(data=>{
      console.log("guardado!!!!");

    })

  }

}




        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddDbContext<AplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DevConnection")));
             services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("AllowWebApp",
                 builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod()));
             services.AddControllers();
             services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
             {
                 c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "BankEnd", Version = "v1" });
             }); 

         
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "BankEnd v1"));
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseCors("AllowWebApp");
            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}



namespace BankEnd.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class TarjetaCreditoController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly AplicationDbContext _context;

        public TarjetaCreditoController(AplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<TarjetaCredito>>> GetTarjetaCredito()
        {
            return await _context.TarjetaCredito.ToListAsync();
        }

        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<TarjetaCredito>> GetTarjetaCredito(int id)
        {
            var tarjetaCredito = await _context.TarjetaCredito.FindAsync(id);
            if (tarjetaCredito == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return tarjetaCredito;
        }
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult>PutTarjetaCredito(int id, TarjetaCredito tarjetaCredito)
        {
            if(id != tarjetaCredito?.Id)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            _context.Entry(tarjetaCredito).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!TarjetaCreditoExists(id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
            return NoContent();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<TarjetaCredito>> PostTarjetaCredito(TarjetaCredito tarjetaCredito)
        {
            _context.TarjetaCredito.Add(tarjetaCredito);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return CreatedAtAction("GetTarjetaCredito", new {id = tarjetaCredito?.Id}, tarjetaCredito);


        }

        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<TarjetaCredito>> DeleteTarjetaCredito(int id)
        {
            var tarjetaCredito = await _context.TarjetaCredito.FindAsync(id);
            if(tarjetaCredito == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            _context.TarjetaCredito.Remove(tarjetaCredito);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return tarjetaCredito;
        }
        private bool TarjetaCreditoExists(int id)
        {
            return _context.TarjetaCredito.Any(x => x.Id == id);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: error que me arroja la consola]
aqui esta el error de la consola

[image: NETWORK DE LA CONSOLA]

Comment: Hola. Por ese statusText: "OK" asumo que esto lo responde despues de que back a procesado algo, con esto intuyo que el error esta en Back, pero no se descarta ya que compartiste solo el Componente de Angular, falta el servicio por compartir y seria bueno ver un pantallazo del network de la consola al realizar la peticion para ver como esta saliendo. Si facilitas eso se podria decir mas.

Comment: @JulioDaza listo amigo me dio una idea de lo sucedido al ver el network note que tenia mal una variable y por eso me daba el error gracias por tu comentario me ayudo a solucionarlo

Comment: @BreynnerTesillo por favor, comparte la solución como respuesta, abajo en _Tu Respuesta_

Answer (score 0):

bueno el error era el que me indicaba el network de la consola y es que en mi angular tenia fechaExpiracion mientras en el backend lo tenia como fechaExpedicion por eso no podía tomar el valor porque obviamente no hacia macht con mi api